# Assembly on the Mac

Tags: linux, macos, assembly, virtual-machine

I'm trying to learn assembly language as an "enrichment" exercise.  I have a Mac and seems like the best resources to learn are for Linux.  My only Linux runs off Parallels Desktop for OSX.  Since assembly is OS and Chipset based, will I have lots of extra problems trying to assemble Linux assembly language through a virtual machine?  I understand that OSX Assembly isn't the best to learn with.

Thanks!!

-JP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux and [OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/LowLevelABI/140-x86-64_Function_Calling_Conventions/x86_64.html) on x86-64 use the same [ABI](https://github.com/x86-8/x86-8-docs/blob/master/SPEC/amd/System%20V%20Application%20Binary%20Interface-abi-AMD64.pdf) - at least, calling conventions, stack setup, etc. There are slight differences in the assembly directives. Where they differ is in system calls, but if you're just writing functions, particularly simple leaf functions, it doesn't matter much. Optimizing hot-spots is one of the few reasons for assembly in userland anyway. A minimal OS X function might look like:

```
    .text
    .p2align 4 ## 16-byte aligned start.
    .globl _foo_bar ## leading underscore in name.

_foo_bar:
    ## your code ##
L__some_label_for_jump_destination
    ## more code ##
    ret
```

which is assembled to Mach-O file format. For Linux (GNU assembler) :

```
    .text
    .p2align 4 ## or other.
    .globl foo_bar ## no leading underscore in name.
    .type foo_bar,@function

foo_bar:
    ## your code ##
.L__some_label_for_jump_destination ## dot before label
    ## more code ##
    ret

    .size foo_bar,[.-foo_bar] ## not strictly needed - ELF object info.
```

There are different variations of the `.align` directive, but I've found `.p2align 4` covers both ELF platforms and OS X, so I don't bother with `.align 4,0x90` on OS X. If in doubt just look at some C code assembly output of a simple function: `clang/gcc -c -S foo.c`

Perhaps you would like to try inline assembly first. I can't recommend [this](http://locklessinc.com/articles/gcc_asm/) tutorial enough. Clang accepts [GCC's inline assembly syntax](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm).

Comment: Thanks for the answer...  I'm not entirely sure that's what I'm looking for, but maybe I don't yet understand assembly well enough yet.